# Combine 2 streams

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, gulp

I am trying to customize bootstrap using gulp and gulp-less.

Bootstrap files sit in one folder, my customized in another, and I would like to read all into combined memory streams, and execute less, outputing CSS without copying files around. Is this possible?  I think I need to use the vinyl fs but am new to node and gulp...

This code doesn't work but illustrates what I want to do I hope -

```
gulp.task('compileLess', function(){
    return gulp.src([
        'public/less/custom/*.less',
        'bower_components/bootstrap/less/**/*.less'
    ])
    .pipe(mergeIntoOneInMemoryDir())
    .pipe(grabOneFile('bootstrap.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/compiled-bootstrap.css'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In gulp v4, you will be able to simply add streams to existing ones, but for now to combine two streams, you can use the *merge* of **[event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream)**.

So something like this:

```
var es = require('event-stream');

gulp.task('compileLess', function () {

  var custom = gulp.src('public/less/custom/*.less');
  var bootstrap = gulp.src('bower_components/bootstrap/less/**/*.less');

  return es.merge(custom, bootstrap)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/compiled-bootstrap.css'));
});
```

Comment: this almost works. but I need to pass a specific file from the 2 combined streams to less. it's like I need to do the equivalent of - cp custom/* /working/, cp bootstrap/* /working/, cd /working/, less bootstrap.less.  Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: You can add an infinity of streams to the merge, not sure if that's what you're looking for though.

Comment: I don't understand your example, you want to execute less on only one file but output it as one compiled css?

Comment: Yes - the one less file is the entry point - the "main" file and it has relative references to the other files - it expects them in the same "directory"